# How Jackson-Creating a JsonObject

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to create a JsonObject like this:

```
{
Response: 200,
Lists: [
  {
    Test: "Math",
    Result: "6",
    Credit: "3"
  },
  {
   Test: "C++",
   Result: "10",
   Credit: "6"
  }
 ]
}
```

I know create this with lib org.json but with Jackson?  i try to use

```
JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory = new JsonNodeFactory();
```

but i have this problem

```
The constructor JsonNodeFactory() is not visible
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure to use the latest version of Jackson. They moved from codehaus to FasterXML: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome.

You don't need to instantiate the factory. You can use the public static one: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory.instance`.

```
JsonNodeFactory factory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
ObjectNode root = factory.objectNode();
root.put("Response", 200);
ArrayNode list = factory.arrayNode();
list.add(...);
...
root.set("List", list);
```

Note that Jackson is a great library to map Java POJOs to JSON (and back). Rather than creating the JSON structure by hand, you can create Java classes that Jackson will serialize to JSON:

```
public class Item {
    @JsonProperty("Test")
    private String test;

    @JsonProperty("Result")
    private String result;

    @JsonProperty("Credit")
    private String credit;
}

public class Root {
    @JsonProperty("Response")
    private int response;

    @JsonProperty("List")
    private List<Item> list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Root root = new Root();
    ...
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(root)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a JsonNode object use ObjectMapper. For example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(JSON_STRING, JsonNode.class)
```

Refer to [the Jackson documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) for information.